# Clean up AWS err response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I will preface this post with I am very new to JavaScript and even newer to AWS and their services.

I am currently working through [this AWS tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-sign-up-users-javascript) and I am adapting it to fit my needs. I am not asking to make this work, as I already have it working for my needs.

In this bit of code

```
userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    cognitoUser = result.user;
    console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
});
```

I am having trouble reformatting the `err` received by the `function` call when something goes wrong.

For example, I am using AWS Lambda to check the input validation for server side (using `python`), and I have it `raise Exception("First Name is not long enough")` which is what i get in return. However, when the `alert(err)` is called, correctly, I receive this:

```
UserLambdaValidationException: PreSignUp failed with error First Name is not long enough..
```

I have tried `split` on the `err` but the console says `split` is not a function of `err`.

So my question is, how can I strip this `err` and only get the message instead of the whole `exception`?

I have already tried `err.split("error"); err.value; err.errorMessage; err["value"]; err["errorMessage"]; err.Error;` and it doesn't work.

Also, when I `console.log(err)` I am presented with:

```
Error: First Name is not long enough..(...) //the (...) is the stacktrace
```

Comment: When you `alert(err)` you are implicitly converting it to a string. Maybe try `err.toString().split(':')` or whatever you are splitting it on? You can check this with `console.log(typeof err)` to verify that it is indeed an object. But your `console.log(err)` should show (in the dev tools) an expandable object that you can inspect, at least in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Comment: @mherzig YES! I didn't even think about `toString()` and how `alert()` implicitly calls it. This, infact did work. Thank you.